# Google Chrome ignores Google Font subset

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, google-font-api

I'm using a pretty common font-family, Open Sans, trying to load multiple weights & latin as the only subset (which is optional, as it is supported by default), it all goes great with every browser, apart from Google Chrome.

`@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700,800&subset=latin');`

It looks great in Firefox / IE, but in Chrome, the subset is ignored and the browser gets all the subsets & their unicode ranges, and downloads them according to the type of characters found throughout the page. I know that this behaviour is intended.

For example, font-weight: 600 (semibold) and 800 (extrabold) look exactly like 700. If I remove all the subsets from the source and load only the latin subset of each weight, it works great in Chrome too.

Is there any easy way I can force Google to serve that specific subset only, no matter what? I know there are several other ways to load a font.

Answer (score 3):

As you already mentioned in your question, [in a browser that supports `unicode-range`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=font-unicode-range) the subset is dynamically served, there's no need (or way) to force it.

Just don't include in the DOM any Unicode characters from the subsets you don't want. This will prevent any aware browser from downloading unnecessary font files.

Also, the `latin` subset is included by default, so there's also no need to specify it.

Just include other subsets for browsers that doesn't support `unicode-range`.

Answer (score 1):

Modern browsers like Chrome download fonts range that they need and used on the web page so setting something like "subset" is unnecessary.

> it means they download the available subsets based on the unicode
> characters in the DOM.

Check out this issue for more information: [subset problem #113](https://github.com/google/fonts/issues/113)